# File deletion in Java

Tags: java, file, delete-file

Every 5 minutes in a thread I create new files and store them into a folder.

Every day at 11:10 A.M., I have to delete the old files. However, one condition is that to be deleted a file must have been created before this 11:00 A.M. Files created after 11:00 should not be deleted. How can I list the files at 11:10 and delete those from before 11:00? How to delete just those files? Please can anyone help me?

Comment: I'd say RTFM: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: Romain: at least link to the current version: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html (otherwise Google will keep thinking that Java 1.4.2 is still interesting).

Answer (score 2):

There are various methods available in the [`File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class which can help.

- To list the files in a directory use the [`listFiles`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) method. This will return an array of Files which you can iterate over.
- To check when a file was last modified use the [`lastModified`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29) method.
- To delete a file use the [`delete`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29) method.

You also need to work out the value of 11:10am so that it can be compared to the file's last modified time. You can use the [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class for this.

Answer (score 1):

First you should create a cronjob or a scheduled task that runs your java application at arround 11:10.

For determining if the file needs to be deleted check out the API of "File" (e.g. "lastModified()" and "delete()":
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html